# javac failing with the error JNU_GetStringPlatformChars: referenced symbol not found

Tags: java, javac, java-7

My Java class is like this;

```
import oracle.sqlj.runtime.Oracle;
import sqlj.runtime.ref.DefaultContext;

class Test
{

  public static void main (String args[]) throws SQLException

  {

    Connection conn=null;;
    PreparedStatement ps=null;

   Oracle.connect(TestInstallCreateTable.class, "connect.properties");

 conn = DefaultContext.getDefaultContext().getConnection();

 try {
    ps = conn.prepareStatement("DROP TABLE SALES");

    ps.executeUpdate();

 } catch (SQLException e) {
         ;             
 }

}
}
```

I am seeing the following error with javac with jdk7.

```
ld.so.1: javac: fatal: relocation error: file 
/jdk7/jre/lib/sparc/libzip.so: symbol JNU_GetStringPlatformChars: referenced symbol not found
```

Why does it occur?

Comment: Have you included all your imports?  It looks like you're missing some.

Comment: is there ld.so in usr/lib/ ??

Comment: I am seeing the failure with 32 bit mode.

Comment: javac -d32 Test.java. We are seeing the error. javac -d64 we are not seeing the error.

Comment: This is a problem with your Java installation (specifically the zip implementation used to load javac's classes or the Java runtime), not with the source code shown here.

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed ia32-libs on your machine? I have seen similar errors when trying to run 64bit java in 32bit mode on an amd64 linux instance without that library installed.

Installing that library (in my case with `apt-get install ia32-libs` on debian) solved the problem.